# How to change skeletal mesh with multiple .uc files in runtime

Tags: unreal, udk

My plan for this is kind of complicated. I want to create a world where you can find things and place them around the map. But I don't want it to be too complicated. If my character had the ability to shoot cars, for example, I'd imagine the cars natural collision in the editor would still work and I wouldn’t have to specify it in the code. I also want to be able to make movie sequences using two code files running instantaneously, for example.

Apparently there is a timer function in UDK but it looks really complicated. I'm hoping not to use it. I'm not really a developer but with just being able to change the skeletal mesh using timers on the fly I can create an entire game out of it without much experience. What I'm also hoping to do though is by having these objects in the room. In other words: they're not abstracts. They essentially act like variables that change other things in the code.

**I want to figure out how to change skeletal mesh with a variable in the code with multiple .uc files extending the file where the skeletal mesh is changed in Unreal Engine 3.**

Basically, in Unreal Engine you can extend files.

This is in `UT_Weap_CustomWeapon_Content`

```
Begin Object name=PickupMesh
SkeletalMesh=SkeletalMesh'A.okay'
PhysicsAsset=PhysicsAsset'A.okay_Physics'
CollideActors=true
BlockActors=true
BlockRigidBody=true
End Object
Components.Add(PickupMesh)
CollisionComponent=PickupMesh
Mesh=PickupMesh
```

I want to overwrite this file when another object is added to the room.
the problem is, I don't know how to update that object even within the same Unreal class or uc file.

I tried to copy and paste the object again but this causes the system to hang.

I've tried creating an object with the same vars as `PickupMesh` in `PickupFactory` and `UtWeapon` then I tried setting `PickupMesh=Replace` after creating an object with a different skeletal mesh.

```
Begin Object name=Replace
SkeletalMesh=SkeletalMesh'A.b'
PhysicsAsset=PhysicsAsset'A.b_Physics'
CollideActors=true
BlockActors=true
BlockRigidBody=true
End Object
Components.Add(Replace)
CollisionComponent=Replace
Mesh=Replace

PickupMesh=Replace
```

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know really. With Kactors and kismet you can easily change a kactor to a different static mesh and you can also spawn actors with a static mesh. these can be created without lighting using a fbx file in 3ds. these will show up pitch black if you try to import them normally. however spawning them through create actor in kismet will allow them to show up. Kismet is fairly easy but here are some things that tripped me up. ctrl left click allows you to move kismet objects. this is very helpful as without it kismet never really places your kismet objects where youd like them. another thing thats helpful is the instigator class. go to variables create object and youll see three ? marks attach that to any class marked instigator. instigator is used by unreal to mean the object that initiated the action. changing things to skeletal meshes using uc code is cumbersome. for the most part kismet works for a far amount of things.

However im sure there are things it can't do. Currently im working on getting 2 players to work with local multiplayer so the game can be played through Parsec. this has to be done through uc code.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question.